# Got "symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64" errors when archive

Tags: ios, archive, cpu-architecture, arm64

I can run my app on 4s/5s/6/6s/6plus without any problems, but when I archive, I've got lots of "*symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64*" errors. 

I've tried many solutions on the internet, but still can't fix it. Can anybody help me with this?

ps. I manage all the third-party libraries with CocoaPods.

Here is the detail of the errors:-

[image: detail of the errors]

Here are my build settings:-

[image: build settings]